# Material 2 sidenav not working properly. css not getting displayed

Tags: angular, angular2-material

[image]Angular2 material checkbox, toolbar, nd button components are getting displayed with css. But sidenav is not getting displayed with css. Image provided above.

Used code from

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/sidenav

```
  <md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #start (open)="mybutton.focus()">
        Start Sidenav.
        <br>
        <button md-button #mybutton (click)="start.close()">Close</button>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-sidenav #end align="end">
        End Sidenav.
        <button md-button (click)="end.close()">Close</button>
    </md-sidenav>

    My regular content. This will be moved into the proper DOM at runtime.
</md-sidenav-layout>

    My regular content. This will be moved into the proper DOM at runtime.
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Component file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
import { MdCheckbox } from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
import { MdButton } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdToolbar } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';

@Component({
    selector: "my-sidebar",
    templateUrl: "app/sidebar.component.html",
    directives: [MdCheckbox, MdSidenav, MdButton, MdToolbar]
})
export class SidebarComponent {

}
```

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, could you retry with after updating both angular & angular material ? If it is still not working after that, could you link your css here so we can help you ?